# Is OCaml's type system static?

Tags: compiler-construction, static, ocaml, interpreter, type-systems

It is mentioned in various sources that OCaml has a static and strong type system, and also that it is an interpreted language.

Wikepedia states  that static type checking is done at compile time. Now if OCaml is not a compiled language, then how does static type checking apply to it?

It is also mentioned in some places that OCaml has a byte code compiler and a VM. Then how does OCaml figure when to behave as an interpreted language and when to behave as a compiled language?

Comment: 'Compile time' is a loose term in programing that general means 'not runtime', I.E. it is done through static analysis of the source code. More broadly speaking, a static type system simple means that every variable is declared to have a type, and the type of the variable can never change (beyond polymorphic constraints).

Comment: A good question would link to these “various sources”.

Comment: Define "interpreted". It's a pretty vague thing, you won't be able to distinguish compiled and interpreted language implementations easily.

Comment: And in order to blow up your mind a bit further, take a look at Typed Racket. It does the type checking and lowering pretty early, while still keeping a dynamically typed backend. Another similar example is TypeScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OCaml comes with an interpreter and two compilers. The interpreter reproduces the behavior of the compiler quite faithfully as you enter one expression at a time. It does a static type analysis of each expression. If the typing is OK, it evaluates the expression.

So, OCaml doesn't have to decide when to be a compiler and when to be an interpreter. The user decides by running the interpreter (commonly called the "toplevel") when that's what they want to do. Or, they run one of the compilers if they want to produce code for running later.

One of the compilers produces native code (machine code), for a set of supported machines. The other compiler produces bytecodes for a virtual machine that works in many more environments. There are tradeoffs between the two kinds of code; generally, the native code is faster but the bytecode is more portable and supports more interesting types of debugging (including running the program in reversed time).

Comment: OCaml bytecode interpreter does not "reproduce the behaviour of the compiler". It simply executes the bytecode produced by a compiler. And the bytecode is, of course, already stripped from the type information.

Comment: @SK-logic you are confusing the top-level (interpreter) and the byte code virtual machine.

Comment: @LeoWhite, Jeffrey clearly meant something else but REPL, because REPL does not "reproduce the behaviour of the compiler", it is exactly the same compiler.

Comment: For each expression you type in REPL, the REPL does a type analysis, then (if the type is OK) it evaluates the expression. That's all I'm trying to say. My point is that the types are just as strong and static as in compiled code. It's a good point about the bytecode interpreter (or VM). It would be helpful to include in the overview I was trying to write.

Answer (score 4):

Static type checking occurs *before* any code is run. This is the case in OCaml, its typechecker runs before the interpreter or the compiler kicks in, and you get type errors if something is wrong.

Dynamic type checking occurs *during runtime*, every time the variable in question is used. For example - Racket or Scheme. In those, you can get a type error during program's execution.